# Is there a shorter way to assign a value than with an "if-else" chain?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, optimization

Right now, my code is something like this:

```
var day = getDay(); //A function that gets this current day of the week as integer
var dayname = "";
if (day==0) dayname = "Su";
if (day==1) dayname = "Mo";
...
if(day==6) dayname = "Sa";
```

It works, but I feel like it could be way shorter, something like this:

```
if (day == (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)) dayname = ("Su","Mo",...,"Sa");
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Define a array `var dayNames = ["Su","Mo",...,"Sa"]` and `dayname = dayNames[getDay()] ` not need of `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var dayname = days[getDay()];
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have to do the opposite (e.g. getting the number from the string)?

Comment: `var day_number = days.indexOf(day);` //where day is 'Monday' or 'Saturday' or whatever ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var dayNames = ['mo', 'tu', 'we', 'th', 'fr', 'sa', 'su'];
var dayName = dayNames[getDay()];
```

This way there is no `if` statement. If `day` starts at 1 and ends at 7, you can do:

```
var dayName = dayNames[getDay() - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach

Define an array as `var days = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tue', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];` and use the index `0-6` to select the particular day.

So, if `getDay();` returns `0` then  it will store `sun` in `dayname`

```
var day = getDay(); //A function that gets this current day of the week as integer
var days = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tue', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var dayname = days[day];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a lookup table:

```
var day = getDay();
var daysByNumber = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'];
var dayName = daysByNumber[day];
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way of doing this is by using dictionaries

```
    var day = getDay();
    dict = {0: 'Monday', 1: 'Tudesday', 2: 'Wednesday', 3: 'Thursday', 4: 'Friday', 5: 'Saturday', 6: 'Sunday'}
    dayname=dict[day]
    print(dayname)
```